# Get parent directory of CWD in Java

Tags: java, file

I am using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`  to get my CWD.
I then trim off the last \token to give me the parent directory.

My question is ,  is there any easier way to do it?  I want the current working directory,  `cd` up one level and then drill into a sub folder in another project.

I run my unit tests in `\\projectA\test`  but I want to get the path to another folder contained in a project at the same level.  ie folder `\\projectB\otherTestData`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check `getparent` and `getParentFile` methods in [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.

For more details see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)